# Does char array contain string?

Tags: c, string, search, char, contains

I have a text file and would like to check if it contains a string.
The text file is stored in a char array: `char buffer[512][128];`.

Q1: Is it easier if I buffer it in one long array instead of a multidimensional array?
Q2: How could I check whether the buffer contains the string `char *s1 = "Hello world!";`?
    I will need to search for multiple strings.

Comment: Are the multiple strings you're searching for constant, or user-supplied arguments? Are you looking to match any, or all, or some amount in between? `strstr` will work but we can optimize based on some of those requirements.

Comment: @Chris Lutz The strings are all different... I have an array with those. I would check if they exist in the old file, if not then i'd add them

Comment: Okay then. Since you need to check each one individually and add them if they exist, `strstr` is the way to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. It will be much easier to use a single 1D array.
2. [`strstr(buffer, s1)` != null](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) (once you've changed `buffer` into a 1D array)

Answer (score 9):

[`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/)