# Search for string in char array

Tags: c

I'm attempting to search for a string in a character array whereby the string to be identified is UCAST and whereby the character array is as follows:

```
analysis_buffer[0] = \n;
analysis_buffer[1] = U;
analysis_buffer[2] = C;
analysis_buffer[3] = A;
analysis_buffer[4] = S;
analysis_buffer[5] = T;
analysis_buffer[6] = \r;
```

The code I executed to attempt the search procedure is as follows:

```
            constant char str[] = "UCAST";
        char* pch = strstr(analysis_buffer,str);

        if (pch!=NULL) {
            printf("found at %d\n", pch - analysis_buffer + 1);

            pch = strstr(pch+1, analysis_buffer);
        } else {
            printf("pch :%s\n", pch);
        }
```

NOTE: analysis_buffer is the array I described above.

The problem I'm encountering is that the strstr bit amounts to NULL while it shouldn't. Any ideas?

I've had a look at the following links on stackoverflow for help:

[Does char array contain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557557/does-char-array-contain-string)

[How to search a string in a char array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450809/how-to-search-a-string-in-a-char-array-in-c)

THANKS

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't change the original question in response to posted answers. It is confusing for people coming to the question and makes posted answers superfluous.

Comment: Apologies ..  wont do that again

Comment: Does it compile? What do actually assign to `analysis_buffer`?

Comment: Hi all, it compiles when  set y analysis_buffer as a char buffer as indicated by hmjd. Apologies but I forgot to mention that analysis_buffer is an int8 array not a char array hence it is still NOT working. Please see my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011923/copy-byte-int8-array-elements-to-char-array whereby I'm asking how to copy a elements from an int8 array into a char array

Answer (score 3):

The code is incorrect as the array is one element too short for the initializer:

```
char str[5] = "UCAST";
```

due to implicit null character added to all string literals. From section *6.4.5 String literals* point 5 of the C99 standard:

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literal. ...

Possible fixes:

- allow the deduction of the required array size:

  ```
  char str[] = "UCAST";
  ```
- use a `const char*` as it is unrequired for `str` to be modified:

  ```
  const char* str = "UCAST";
  ```

Note that the string being searched (`analysis_buffer` in this case) must be null terminated also. From the posted code it is not apparent that this is happening.

Additionally, the final `printf()` statement is incorrect as the format specifier is `%c` but the argument (`pch`) type is `char*`. Normally, either use `%s` and use `pch` or use `%c` and `*pch` **BUT** `pch` is `NULL` in this branch of the `if` so it cannot used in the `printf()`.

Comment: Ah I see .. so how do I store the string I would like to search for .. may be like this .. char str[] = "UCAST";

Comment: @user34395, refresh your page as i have that in this answer.

Comment: just saw it. lemme try it out.

Comment: Also note that `char str[] = "...";` allocates the string on the stack (so it uses 6 bytes of stack space in this case), which may be a problem depending on what you want to do (probably not in this case). In order to not use stack space for the string itself, use `char* str = "..."` -- but note that the string cannot be modified in this case.

Comment: @hmjd: I've applied the constant char as seen in the edited code in my orginal post but it doesn't work. analysis_buffer is the char array to be searched and it is null terminated. I've also changed the %c to %s as I'll stick to using pch.

Comment: @user34395, not sure what the issue is so here is a quick example http://ideone.com/KjaJRp .

Comment: Apart from strstr which other methods could be useful for the searching of a string in a char array?