# Copy byte/int8 array elements to char array

Tags: c

I have an int8 array essentially declared as a BYTE array at the top of my program.

I want to copy the contents of this array into char array for processing. The content in my byte array is as follows:

```
byte_array[0] = "A";
byte_array[1] = "Q";
byte_array[2] = "W";
byte_array[3] = "E";
byte_array[4] = "R";
byte_array[5] = "T";
byte_array[6] = "Y";
byte_array[0] = "Z";
byte_array[1] = ".";
byte_array[2] = ".";
byte_array[3] = ".";
```

And my code is as follows:

```
char char_array[];

for (j = 0; j < byte_array_size; j++) {
    char_array = &byte_array[j];

    printf("char_array[j]: %c - j: %u\n\r", char_array[j], j);
            }
```

Note: j and byte_array_size are declared at the top of my program and are intialised with 0 and 10 respectively. byte_array has been populated as mentioned at the start of the post.

The printf above is essentially printing out spurious characters rather than:

```
char_array[0] = "A";
char_array[1] = "Q";
char_array[2] = "W";
char_array[3] = "E";
char_array[4] = "R";
char_array[5] = "T";
char_array[6] = "Y";
char_array[0] = "Z";
char_array[1] = ".";
char_array[2] = ".";
char_array[3] = ".";
```

Comment: char literal should be 'A' instead of "A". ditto.

Comment: check if you have initiated your chars correctly or you just store the ls byte of the pointer to random strings

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
char char_array[char_array_size];

for (j = 0; j < byte_array_size && j < char_array_size; j++) {
    char_array[j] = byte_array[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char_array = &byte_array[j];`
you are copying the addresses ,
to copy the values u should `char_array[j] = byte_array[j];`

also you should allocate the `char_array` if you don't know it's size use `malloc`
if you do know it use `char char_array[YOUR_SIZE];`